# Java regular expression nested

Tags: java, regex

I have big prob with regular expressions in JAVA (spend 3 days!!!). 
this is my input string:

```
#sfondo: [#nome: 0, #imga: 0],#111: 222, #p: [#ciccio:aaa, #caio: bbb]
```

I need parse this string to array tree, must match like this:

```
group: #sfondo: [#nome: 0, #imga: 0]
group: #111: 222
group: #p: [#ciccio:aaa, #caio: bbb]
```

with or wythout nested brackets

I've tryed this:

```
"#(\\w+):(.*?[^,\]\[]+.*?),?"
```

but this group by each element separate with "," also inside brackets

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Untitled {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "#sfondo: [#nome: 0, #imga: 0],#111: 222, #p: [#ciccio:aaa, #caio: bbb]";
    String regex = "(#[^,\\[\\]]+(?:\\[.*?\\]+,?)?)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println("group: " + matcher.group());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: small exeption:
result: #p: [#ciccio:aaa, #caio: bbb, #ggg: [#fff:aaa]
shuld be: #p: [#ciccio:aaa, #caio: bbb, #ggg: [#fff:aaa]]

Comment: this is correct:
String regex = "(#[^,\\[\\]]+(?:\\[.*?\\]+)?)";

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for your example:

```
    String input = "#sfondo: [#nome: 0, #imga: 0],#111: 222, #p: [#ciccio:aaa, #caio: bbb]";
    String regex = "#\\w+: (\\[[^\\]]*\\]|[^\\[]+)(,|$)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String group = matcher.group();
        matches.add(group.replace(",", ""));
    }
```

**EDIT:** 
This only works for a nested depth of one. There is no way to handle a nested structure of arbitrary depth with regex. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/1343161) answer for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot.This work great but not with nested brackets like:
"#sfondo: [#nome: 0, #imga: 0],#111: 222, #p: [#ciccio:aaa, #caio: bbb, #ggg: [#fff:aaa]]" (see: "#ggg")

Comment: This is correct:
String regex = "(#[^,\\[\\]]+(?:\\[.*?\\]+)?)";

Comment: That doesn't work for the following string though:
"#sfondo: [#nome: 0, #imga: 0],#111: 222, #p: [#ciccio:aaa, #ggg: [#fff:aaa], #caio: bbb]"